# Saving bitmap data as plain text

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, text-files

I'm searching for a way of saving a bunch of little images into one (text-) file with C#.

I was thinking about having a 2D loop (2 nested for loops) that gets the pixel data (rgb value) and writes it as a string into a file.

Are there more elegant ways of doing this? Maybe saving as hex color or uint instead ? ( #FF00FF / 0xFF00FF )

How could I structure the final text file so that it is nice to read afterwards (I want to encrypt the text file with a custom algorithm).

Comment: I would use Base64, similar to what is done for embedding images into HTML pages using the [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: What you choose all depends on what you want. I don't see that you have an actual problem here so I voted to close it. You need to decide what your needs are and make a decision based on that

Answer (score 3):

You can open the Picture as Binary and transform it to Base64, then you can save it as a string to a textfile.

```
    public static string CreateFileStringFromPath(string tempPath)
    {
        //We Convert The Image into a BASE64 String and so store it as text
        //First we add a Stream to the File
        FileStream tempStream = new FileStream(tempPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        try
        {
            //Then we write the Stream to a Byte Array
            byte[] tempByteArray = ReadStreamFully(tempStream);
            tempStream.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            tempStream.Dispose();
            return null;
        }

        //Then we Convert the Byte Array to a Base64 String and return it
        return Convert.ToBase64String(tempByteArray);
    }

    public static byte[] ReadStreamFully(Stream tempFileStreamInput)
    {
        //We Create a MemoryStream which we can form into an Byte Array
        using(MemoryStream tempMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            tempFileStreamInput.CopyTo(tempMemoryStream);
            return tempMemoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Now that we have a String we only need a way to store them, since you want to store them on disk consider XML (and maybe an XSD Stylesheet) or insert them in any other serilazable structure like JSON

EDIT 1: Upon request, here is a method to save the Pixels

```
private Color[,] GetPixel_Example(Bitmap myBitmap)
{
Color[,] tempColor = new Color[myBitmap.width,myBitmap.height]
for(int i = 0; i < myBitmap.height;i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < myBitmap.width;j++)
    // Get the color of a pixel within myBitmap.
    Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(j,i);
    //And save it in the array
    tempColor[j,i] = pixelColor;
return tempColor;
}
```

This example naturally just works with Bitmaps and returns you a 2 dimensional array in which all pixels are saved as Color, now one can extract the RGB or HEX or whatever. You can easily change the example to System.Media.Images or just files. If you don't know how to make your Pictures to Bitmaps, there should be something like Bitmap.LoadFromFile();

Comment: How has this got an upvote? It's just a suggestion on what to do, there is no code to show how to do it. Also, I don't think Base64 qualifies as "nice to read". I think this should have been a comment at best

Comment: @musefan I think that he asked for a way to do it not a step by step advise or code, it's a suggestion just like you said. If you want i can provide the complete code here. :)

Comment: Bit more comprehensive than mine now. :p

Comment: my images are very tiny ( most case 32x32 px ) i think i just want to store the pixel color values ( as RGB or hex ) in a 2d array in string format.

Comment: @Ace, if you want to store the pixel colors, why do you want to use strings? You can store RGB in unsigned byte (numbers from 0 to 255, just like rgb). That way you will have really small files, strings will be bigger.

Comment: well the edit is pretty much what i was thinking about to do. but the question was about the final structure of the ( text ) file that contains a bunch of little bitmaps in a way that i can read just fine afterwards.

Comment: 255,0,0; 0,255,0; 0,0,255; ...; ...; this would not be very elegant i think.

Comment: ff0000, 00ff00, 0000ff, ..., ... , and this one is also a little problematik i think... so what kind of methon can i else use ?

Comment: @Ace, give me a few minutes i have something for you

Comment: This here should help you, please ask if you have further questions,
http://pastebin.com/LdpgUg0q
I did not past it here because it's a huge ammount of useless autogenerated code

Comment: allright thx. i'll try this later. the most important is the output. i'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

As you have multiple images. Do a structured file, say xml
e.g.

```
<Images>
 <Image name = "somename.someimageextension"
 <Content></Content>
</Image>
</Images>
```

To get content, get your image (from disk ?) as a stream, Convert it to base64 with something like

```
string contentAsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageAsStream.ToArray());
```

Encrypt/sign the entire document.